# Remove API 1.x menu from the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta

Now that version 1.x of the API is [on its way out the door](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/) permanently, can we go ahead and drop the associated menu from the sidebar?

[image: freehand crossout is the ultimate deprecation]